# Adding WHERE condition in "Calculations" tab of SSAS Cube Designer

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I have an existing calculated measure in my SSAS cube `[Total Hours]`. The expression for this is:

```
([Measures].[working Hours] + [Measures].[working minutes]/60)
```

I have to create a new Measure by adding a where condition to the above calculated measure like:
`[Measures].[Status Flag] = 'YES'`

How can I add a where condition to an existing calculated measure?

I tried to use the existing Measure like this and create the new one. Is this right?

```
[Measures].[Total Hours] & ([Measures].[Status Flag] = 'YES')
```